# PictureBox events not firing when it's embeded in a user control

Tags: vb.net

VB PictureBox_mouseEnter() event not firing when the picture box is placed inside a custom control

I need to write code to do different things when a mouse enters and leaves a PictureBox (used to display images).  When I place the PictureBox directly on a WindowsForm, the _mouseEnter() event works fine. But if I put the PictureBox on a custom control, and add the control to a WindowsForm, the _mouseEnter() event never fires.  Why?
The reason I want to embed the PicturBox in a custom control is that I can reuse the custom control on other Windows Forms.
Thank you for your insights.

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: it probably *does* fire, but it is seen in the User Control not the host of the host of the picture box (the form)

Comment: Once inside a user control, the picture box is no longer a "picture box" to the form, but a part of that control. As plutonix states, the event must be firing inside the user control.Either handle it from inside the user control, or add to the control an event inside the picture box event in your user control.

Comment: Josh Part is right.  The user control can 'see' the event fired by the picture box, but not the form.  Thanks much.